# Perl regex lookahead issue

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I am new to Perl and need to know a pattern to help me check the following:

```
$string="test1\n   //   test2   \n test3 ";
```

I want a pattern to check that `test2` is not commented. I read about positive and negative look aheads and tried to implement the same but it didn't work for me.

Here's the code snippet:

```
$string = "test3\n//test2\ntest3";

if ($string =~ /(?!\/\/)test2*/) {
  $matched = $&;
  print("$matched");
}
else {
  print("No comments before test2");
}
```

Could somebody please help with the above pattern?

Comment: What is your output? By the way, it looks like your regex checks that `test2` is *not* commented (`?!` is negative lookahead) so the `else` print should be "Comment before test2"

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, my first concern is that your `else` statement says that "test2" wasn't commented but this seems to be the opposite of what your regex looks for.

Second, look-ahead looks *forward* into the string, i.e. it is useful to match characters *after* your pattern. To match characters *before* your pattern you need to look *backwards*. You can do this using look-behind:

```
if($string =~ /(?<!\/\/)test2*/)
```

Here's [a tutorial on Perl look-ahead and look-behind](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) that should give you some more information.

Comment: Why have you got *zero or more `2` characters* at the end there?

Comment: @Borodin Because I copy and pasted the OP's regex, made it look-before instead of look-ahead, but changed nothing else. Why the OP wanted it to be 0 or more `2`s, I have no idea.

Comment: I wasn't able to develop a logic with the positive and negative look ahead as negative lookahead doesnot support regex nd came up with the small code.I wanted to check for multiline comments too. could this be further optimized?
<pre><code>
$string = "test3\n/*\ntest2  */\ntest3\n//test2";
$i=0;
while(1)
{
if(($string =~ m|\/\/(\s*)test2|s)||(($string =~ m|\/*(.*)test2(.*)*\/|s)))
{
$matched = $&;
print("\nMatch found:$matched\n\n");}
elsif(($string =~ m|test2|)){
print("\nTest2 found without comments");
last;}
else{
print("\nNo result");
last;}
$string=substr($string,$+[0]);}
</pre></code>

Comment: @userknight You are correct that look-ahead and look-behind require a fixed length pattern (for implementation purposes, I assume) however that doesn't mean you can't use regex. Have you considered [using regex's group feature](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups)? Also, since you originally asked about look-ahead but now you want to try something else you should accept an answer (if you feel any answers deserves to be accepted) and start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Load `Regexp::Common` from CPAN https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Common and use its `Regexp::Common::comment`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------

use charnames qw( :full :short );
use English qw( -no_match_vars ) ;  # Avoids regex performance penalty

my $string="test1\n    //  test2   \n test3 ";

use Regexp::Common qw( comment );

if( $string =~ m/ ( $RE{comment}{'C++'} ) /msx ){
  my $comment = $1;
  if( $comment =~ m{ test2 }msx ){
    print $comment;
  }else{
    goto NO_COMMENTS_TEST2;
  }
}else{

  NO_COMMENTS_TEST2:
  print "No comments before test2\n";
}
```

Comment: Everything: a quote from the original post, "I want a pattern to check that test2 is not commented." It is better to use a tested and debugged module from CPAN then write your own.

Comment: So add to your answer a demonstration of using `Regexp::Common::comment` to discover whether `test2` isn't commented.

Comment: That just detects whether there are any comments in the entire string. If `test3` were commented but not `test2` then your test would produce the wrong result.

Comment: OK, it now tests for "test2".

Answer (score 0):

Is there more than one occurrence of `test2`?

This will check whether there is a commented occurrence of `test2` in the string

```
$str =~ m|//[^\S\n]*test2|;
```

so

```
$str !~ m|//[^\S\n]*test2|;
```

will tell you whether there are *no* commented occurrences of `test2`.

Comment: I wasn't able to develop a logic with the positive and negative look ahead as negative lookahead doesnot support regex nd came up with the small code.I wanted to check for multiline comments too. could this be further optimized?
$string = "test3\n/*\ntest2  */\ntest3\n//test2";
$i=0;
while(1)
{
if(($string =~ m|\/\/(\s*)test2|s)||(($string =~ m|\/*(.*)test2(.*)*\/|s)))
{
$matched = $&;
print("\nMatch found:$matched\n\n");}
elsif(($string =~ m|test2|)){
print("\nTest2 found without comments");
last;}
else{
print("\nNo result");
last;}
$string=substr($string,$+[0]);}